# open crystal report dynamic hyperlinks in new tab or window

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have crystal report,which list of documents uploaded as hyperlinks.
the crystal report is displayed in aspx page as pdf file. what i needed is the when clicking on hyperlinks in report it must be opened in new tab/window.i have added a screen shot of the list part.

[image]

Comment: add *target* property to your hyperlinks. *target = "_blank"* will open them in new tab

Comment: Khazratbek can you suggest me how to add target in crystal report.i have added already added HyperlinkTarget="_blank" and 
+'{?sWindow=New}' in hyperlink formula editor,but not working

Comment: add *hyperlink="_target"* to your hyperlink

Comment: Another approach is that Crystal Report Viewer has property called *HyperlinkTarget*, you may set that to *_blank*. Example: <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crvReportView" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" HyperlinkTarget="_blank" />

Comment: and keep in mind that if you want to use parameters, you have to add *?sWindow=New*, not *{sWindow=New}*

Comment: and keep in mind that if that will work only if your url does not contains parameters. If it does, you have to use *&sWindow=New* instead of *?sWindow=New*

Comment: i am searching for location to add hyperlink="_target" in report